# How to run Firefox without a display?

Tags: firefox, php

I have written a script in php that requires a browser such as Firefox to run since it contains javascript bits.

I do not need any output from the process, I just need it to trigger the page, run the page along with the javascript, and then close. Now, I am doing this on a VPS, so I do not have a display.

Is there a work around for running Firefox without a display?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try running the script with the command-line browser 'links'

```
links -no-g http://your.sript.here
```

Or you could try a stand-alone JavaScript shell to interpret your code without opening a browser. 
These Webpages might help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Shells

Answer (score 0):

Try xvfb!  It's a display emulator requiring no actual display.

```
apt-get install xvfb
xvfb-run [your script here]
```

man page:
http://man.he.net/man1/xvfb-run

description:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

similar SO topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb